# parse and replace in oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am new to the SQL/Oracle, and wondering if there's an easy way to parse a csv string and replace tokens with another string.

for example, i have a string like

param,value1,str1,param,value2,str3,param,value3

and i want to replace the value after the param with a CONSTANT

so, the string would become

param,CONSTANT,str1,param,CONSTANT,str3,param,CONSTANT

thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to use SQL and Oracle for this?  A simple find and replace should suffice.  Or, the question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [REGEXP_REPLACE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm#i1305521)

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(
           str,'[^,]*','CONSTANT',1,3),'[^,]*','CONSTANT',1,9),'[^,]*','CONSTANT',1,15)
from
   (select 'param,value1,str1,param,value2,str3,param,value3' str from dual);
```

If you have anything messy (like quoted values including commas) then it will break. That said regular expressions aren't my strong point and some should eb able to do a better job.

I presume you know that having a RDBMS like Oracle and storing the data in such an odd manner is a pretty poor idea. If you are not going for a convetional table/column structure, you can use the object relation features or XML.

Answer (score 0):

For that i create package with regular expressions with look-around - see on http://github.com/xtender/XT_REGEXP
Example:

```
with t as 
     (select 'param,value1,str1,param,value2,str3,param,value3' str from dual)
select xt_regexp.replace_all(str,'(?<=param,)[^,]*','CONSTANT') from t
```

(?<=param,) - it is look-ahead regular expression